# How I can store images in Database by using url to images

Tags: python, django, database, image

My problem is that I want to store images in database, but I don't want to store them physically in my project as static files, I want to save in database url to images which are already uploaded somewhere in Internet. How can I do this, just use CharField or TextField as type of field and paste url? But I also want later to display this photo in my template.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Image name')
    image_file = 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: your mean that you want to use external image link in you project?

Comment: Yes, for example some photo I found by google, and I don't wan't to download this photo and store in my project as static file, but I want to use this photo url to store information about him in database and display in template.

Comment: But this url must be also in database, because database must know that this image belong to certain object.

Comment: "How can I do this, just use CharField or TextField as type of field and paste url?" How about a [`URLField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#urlfield)? "But I also want later to display this photo in my template." Okay, what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I just wanted to ask about this before I started project, and I couldn't find much informations about uploading photos by using url so I didn't know if this is good and correct method.

Comment: What does this have to do with uploading? I thought you wanted to hot-link to existing files?

Comment: I mean "uploading" to my page template by displaying this photo on page. Yes its not uploading, I used wrong word to describe this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the external image source link in you django project, all you need is storing image source link in you model which you already did this in you **models.py**:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Image name')
```

But if consider this that you can't use google images source's link because of some limit, read this article to understand why :

[What Happened To Google Image Search And Why You Can No Longer View Images Directly](https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2018/02/what-happened-to-google-image-search-and-why-you-can-no-longer-view-images-directly/) 
by the way you can use **urlfiled** instead of using charfiled, because it's only store urls.  [Django urlfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#urlfield)

after storing your image source link in your model, you can get it in you view the pass it too template and load the image in your template without downloading your image.

if you need any further help, ask and will happy to help.